# i want to scroll webpage from to top navigation buttons to multiple tab of same web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

i want to scroll webpage from top navigation bar which is having buttons, to a section of same webpage which is having multiple tab and i want each button assigned to each tab.

how can i do this.

currently trying using e.g.

```
<a href="#tabA">
<div id="tabA">
```

but above code is not taking to desired path.

i want it like e.g.

```
<a href="#tabA">

<section="one">
<div id="tabA">
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div name="tabA">
```

I don't believe the anchor will look for `id` unless you are using a JS/JQ library you didn't mention.

Comment: please suggest how can i achieve this scenario i am new to js/jq

Comment: If you add/update the `id` to `name` it will work in pure HTML. If you want a jQuery or Javascript solution I would do some Google fu. There are a lot of resources out there that will guide you step by step. If you have problems integrating a JS/JQ solution create a question, show us what you tried and we can try to help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you have above should work natively by the browser unless something else is preventing it (like a library or something).

Here's an example:

```css
.text {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#tabA">go to section A</a>

<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem facere animi similique officiis, totam aliquam velit ea quos at minus laudantium deserunt facilis, fugit vero consectetur, sint impedit cum! Quia!</p>
<section>
  <h1 id="tabA">Section A!</h1>
</section>
```

You can achieve the same results programmatically by locating the top position of the element and telling the `window` to scroll to that position:

```
const rect = document.querySelector('#tabA').getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.scroll(0, rect.top);
```

where `window.scroll` takes two arguments (x, y).

A more recent approach but not widely supported by all browsers is the `Element#scrollIntoView` API.

```
document.querySelector('#tabA').scrollIntoView();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView